# Winsock: recv() on Server is blocking, but client has already moved past send()

Tags: c, winsock2

I am working on a project for school and have run into the following problem. My server is blocking out on recv() despite my client already sending its full message.

This is what I want to happen:

```
Server        Client
recv() <----  send()
send() ---->  recv()
```

This is what is happening:

```
Server        Client
recv() <----  send()
recv() -----  recv()
```

**Some Background**

2 Weeks ago I created the client by itself with an already coded server application. When I coded the client it functioned properly with the provided server, so I want to say that the client is wrong, but I don't know how to get the server that I coded to recognize that no more data will be coming in.

**Code**

Here is the code that I believe is relevant:

Client:

```
    bytesSent = 0;
    retVal = send(sock, phrase, msgLen, 0);
    bytesSent = retVal;
    while (bytesSent < msgLen) {
        retVal = send(sock, phrase + bytesSent, msgLen - bytesSent, 0);
        if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            DisplayFatalErr("send() function failed.");
            exit(1);
        }
        bytesSent += retVal;
        // May need to re-call send in order to keep sending the data.

    }

...

    bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead < msgLen) {
        retVal = recv(sock, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSIZ - 1, 0);
        if (retVal <= 0) {
            DisplayFatalErr("recv() function failed.");
            exit(1);
        }
        bytesRead += retVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal; i++) {
            printf("%c", rcvBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
    char* rcvBuffer[RCVBUFSIZ]; // RCVBUFSIZ = 50
    char* msg = "";
    int bytesRead = 0;
    do {
        if ((bytesRead = recv(clientSock, rcvBuffer, RCVBUFSIZ - 1, 0)) == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (bytesRead < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        char* msgConcatenated;
        int msgLen = strlen(msg);
        msgConcatenated = malloc(msgLen + bytesRead);
        if (msgConcatenated != NULL) {
            int newMsgLen = strlen(msgConcatenated);
            strncpy_s(msgConcatenated, newMsgLen, msg, msgLen);
            strncat_s(msgConcatenated, newMsgLen, rcvBuffer, bytesRead);
            msg = msgConcatenated;
        }
    } while (bytesRead != 0);
```

Let me know if I need to provide extra information.

Comment: regarding: `int msgLen = strlen(msg);`  since the char array `msg` has not been set to anything, especially anything that end in a NUL termination byte, the result is undefined behavior which can lead to anything, including a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `msgConcatenated = malloc(msgLen + bytesRead);`  this results in a memory leak as the original pointer is overlayed ( and therefore forever lost)  Strongly suggest using `realloc()`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem(s) and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `bytesRead += retVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal; i++) {
            printf("%c", rcvBuffer[i]);`  why keep repeating the output of partial messages?  Suggest only outputting the data after it is all received

Comment: @user3629249: I see no undefined behavior with `int msgLen = strlen(msg)`, as, in the first iteration, `msg` points to an empty string, and in further iterations, it points to the last concatenated string. However, you are right that the code contains a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). But the memory leak does not occur in the line you mentioned, because `msgConcatenated` has been saved in `msg`. Instead, the memory leak occurs in the line `msg = msgConcatenated`, as the memory that `msg` previously points to is no longer referenced by any variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), to signal the other end of the socket that no more data will be sent, a packet with the FIN flag set must be sent. This is accomplished in Winsock by calling the function `shutdown` with SD_SEND as the second parameter. This will cause the program on the other end of the socket to no longer block when calling `recv`. Instead, `recv` will return 0 indicating that the connection has been gracefully closed (unless there is data left that has not been read yet). See the [Microsoft documentation on the shutdown function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-shutdown) for further information. [This documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2) also contains some helpful information about graceful socket closure.

Also, as has been pointed out in the comments, your code contains a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) in the following line:

```
msg = msgConcatenated
```

In that line, you reassign `msg` without first freeing the memory that `msg` is pointing to. Unfortunately, fixing that memory leak is not easy, because you can't simply call `free` on `msg` before reassigning it. This is because, in the first iteration of the loop, `msg` can also be pointing to something else than dynamically allocated memory. Therefore, to fix the leak, you would also have to keep track of what type of memory `msg` is pointing to, or make it always point to dynamically allocated memory, even when the string is empty (i.e. when it only contains the terminating null character).

Comment: There is so very much wrong with the OPs posted code, you really should have mentioned all the other problems.  Discussing a method of closing the socket on the server will not help the OP with the other problems

Comment: @user3629249: Thanks for pointing out the memory leak, I have added a reference to it in the answer.